# Etiquetas en Laravel

Tags: php

Soy nueva en el uso de Laravel, previo a esto llevo unos tres años trabajando con Yii Framework y pues quisiera saber si laravel tiene algo parecido a la función **`attributeLabels()`** de Yii, la cual básicamente lo que me permite es modificar una sola vez el nombre de la etiqueta y que este se actualice en todas las vistas en las que lo uso, en Yii lo usaba de la siguiente manera

En la vista

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($modelo,'id'); ?>
```

Y el contenido de la función en el modelo

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'Identificador',
        );
    }
```

Comment: Por favor no devuelvas las ediciones, lo que hacemos es eliminar textos innecesarios y adaptar la pregunta al formato de StackOverflow.

Comment: Me parece que lo que buscan son medallas, realmente no veo que esté mal, por el contrario lo que están haciendo es agregar y quitar cosas sólo para que se vean las ediciones, por eso las revierto. Saludos.

Comment: Si te fijas en mi reputación y mi historial, hace mucho tiempo tengo esas medallas, yo lo hago por contribuir y seguir los lineamientos establecidos en la comunidad.

Comment: Lo sé, y no hablo de usted, pero lo que usted borro son cosas que han ido agregando solo por editar.